# Salesforce Flow Button on a Record Page to automatically fetch record info

Tags: custom-button, lookup, screen-flow, default-value, flow-screen-component

I am trying to create a Custom button on an Opp Record Page to trigger a flow.

I placed the flow Button on Campaign__c Record page. This Object, Campaign__c, has a Masterdetail relationship with Opps and a Lookup with Acc.

The flow is working correctly and if I debug it I get what I want: I start by selecting A record Opp. and the Lookup fields in the screen element get auto populated.
[image: this is where I select the Record]
[image]
(Yeah, sorry for the OPP and ACC names)

When the flow is triggered from a record page I want the Account and Opp lookup fields to be auto-populated in the flow screen.

I honestly don't know how to get there, I have created record variable - Text or Record (tried both)

At the moment this is how is set up the 2 lookup fields in the flow and works (Only) within the debug page:

[image]
[image]

I found a tip where it was suggesting to append a something to the button link: */flow/J_New_Campaign?OppRecordId={!Opportunity.Id}*

Which I don't know if it makes sense.

Thank you all for the help and support.

Comment: Do you meant you want to create Campaign record from Opportunity page using Screenflow. Can you edit the post and let us know what you have tried so far

Comment: I tried to explain myself better. Please check out the updated version of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying something like below to auto-populate Account and Opportunity on screen when we click a button on Opportunity Page.

[image]

I just created a variable as below

[image]

I have used that variable to populate the opportunity and Account details automatically as shown below.

[image]

[image]

I have added this screenflow as action and when I click button on opportunity it is working as expected

Comment: I did exactly the same, the only difference my flow is triggered from a button. if I had to guess the mistake is there;In the  link! 

Also, if I debug and choose a random Opp. the 2 fields get prepopulated properly. 
when I press the button from a record page no "record-related" value is displayed.

Comment: Can you try it by creating an Action

Comment: I will try and let you know if worked, thanks!!

Comment: The error was a wrong reference to the var in the button Link. Is now working properly with button.

Comment: @JACOPOPARISI, Thanks for confirming.